# How to send custom password reset link in laravel (customized link with prefix)?

Tags: laravel

I Laravel custom authentication (Laravel Breeze). I want to send my customized password reset link. In default, the link is sent in this format ***localhost:8000/reset-password/{token}***  but I want to send link ***localhost:8000/system/reset-password/{token}***.

```
Route
// forgot-password
    Route::get('/forgot-password',[AdminForgotPasswordController::class,'create'])->name('admin.showForgotPassword');
    Route::post('/forgot-password',[AdminForgotPasswordController::class,'store'])->name('admin.forgotPassword');
```

```
controller
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ]);
         // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
        // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
        // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
        $status = Password::sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email')
        );


        return $status == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                    ? back()->with('status', __($status))
                    : back()->withInput($request->only('email'))
                            ->withErrors(['email' => __($status)]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [the Laravel documentation about Password Reset](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passwords#reset-link-customization) you would be able to override the password reset link!